# Rails - how to solve this issue of an orphaned migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

After rake db:migrate:rollback STEP=1, rake db:migrate:reset, rake db:migrate:setup, rake db:migrate:up VERSION=XXXXXXXXX I get the following entry:

```
     Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
------------------------------------------------------

       up     0         *********NO FILE**********

       up     20120209023430  Create tasks
```

How can I get rid of the orphaned entry? I have encountered this problem a few times after raking the db similar to above. Could somebody please explain what exactly causes this.

Thx in advance.
Shahram

Answer (score 16):

You could use `rake db:migrate:reset db:seed`. It's a little less verbose and will completely wipe your database, re-run all migrations, and then seed your database from the `db/seeds.rb` file.

Comment: Thx siannopollo, your rakes rock!

Comment: If this worked for you would you accept this as the answer, please?

Comment: I'm curious: why doesn't `rake -T db` list `db:migrate:reset`?  If it weren't for this SO answer, I wouldn't have known about it!

Comment: I think the problem is that db:migrate:reset doesn't have a description. `rake -T` says is will "Display the tasks (matching optional PATTERN) with descriptions, then exit." It seems to be serious about the "with descriptions" part.

Answer (score 0):

I've just released [this gem](https://github.com/widefix/actual_db_schema) that can solve this issue for good.

The idea of that gem is simple. It keeps all migrated migrations inside `tmp` folder so that Git ignores them. It's just only your local story. These files are needed to roll back the "unknown" migrations being in another branch. Now, whenever you have an inconsistent DB schema due to running migrations in some other branch just run `rails db:migrate` inside the current branch and it will fix the issue automatically. The gem does all this magic automatically for you.