# Corrupted schema.rb between branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, schema, branch

I apologise in advance for not being to provide a lot of information about this but I really am in a very weird situation: My `schema.rb` file gets messed up between different git branches, carrying with it database fields at will with the relative migrations just not existing.

When I run `rake db:migrate:status` I get a couple of `********** NO FILE **********`.

Has anyone been in a similar situation? I would appreciate **any** kind of leads for a direction to try.

Comment: If you try recreating your schema from the database and then check the status

rake db:schema:dump

Comment: Here is a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240590/rails-how-to-solve-this-issue-of-an-orphaned-migration

Comment: @Rafal The database is branch-agnostic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the preferred way to manage schema.rb in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737854/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-manage-schema-rb-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is by dropping the database, feeding an older dump to it and then running the remaining migrations on my current branch. Yet another motivation to keep db backups, I guess.